# while loops for rows in PHP

Tags: php

New to php and I'm trying to have 8 rows with 2 cells using a while loop. I can't seem to get it right, I've played with the code a lot but it always comes out wrong. A point in the right direction would be appreciated

```
 <section class="grabber2">
                <?php
                $x = 0;
                    echo '<tr>';
                    while ($x < 4){
                        echo
                        '<td> phrase 1!</td>',
                        '<td> phrase 2!</td>'; 
                        $x++;
                    }
                        ?></tr>
            </section>
```

Comment: Your HTML is completely backwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TR comes before TD. TR=Table Row. TD=Table Column

Try it like this:

```
<table>
     <?php
         $x = 0;
         while ($x < 8){
             echo '<tr>';
             echo '<td> phrase 1!</td><td> phrase 2!</td>'; 
             echo '<tr>';
             $x++;
         }
    ?>
</table>
```

Section tag is useful only to apply css styling to some components. You don't need it in this case. Also, try to use nested `<div>` tags instead of `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is wrong. You need a table tag.

```
<table>
    <?php 
    $x = 1;
    while($x <= 8): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>phrase 1!</td>
            <td> phrase 2!</td>
        </tr>
        <?php $x++;
    endwhile; ?>
</table>
```